# Protecting folder in public_html

Tags: php, javascript, public-html

I have a music sharing site and realize that the files on my site are not necessarily protected as they are stored in a subfolder in public_html.  I need to protect them in a way that they still work for anyone in the music player, which located on a listen.php page.  However, if the user goes directly to a file, such as this http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/mp3/95d246c26a7c003cdac86ead05659b37.m4a.  I do not want them to be able to download the file so as to protect my users.  However, I can not add any code to that page because it is an mp3.  Is there a way to add an index to the folder that would allow for me to add javascript to that page?  I tried using .htaccess but had no luck with it.  If anyone knows how I could possibly solve this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want people to access the files that you, or others, put on the internet you've got two simple options; 1: *don't put them on the internet* or, 2: *put them outside of the web-root*.

Comment: Consider putting the files themselves outside the Web root, and exposing them via a PHP script or similar, so that you can require the user to log in before accessing the file.

Comment: +1 For putting the files outside the web root. Then use  `../../file.m4a` to let PHP access the files.

Comment: Generally if your web-based music player can access it, then your users can grab the file directly. You could however require a special query string that your (Flash-based) music player uses - though this can also be done by savvy users who know how to find out what the query string is. Lastly you could encode/encrypt your music, and decode it in the player - but again this can be subverted.

Comment: Good point from @cbuckley - are you willing to require users to be logged in to listen to your music?

Comment: They do not have to be logged in to listen to the music.  I am working on trying to put the files outside of the web-root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stu Thompson explains a few ways well in this post - [Protect flash video from download/right protect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300749/protect-flash-video-from-download-right-protect) also, this link may be of particular usefulness for you - [Is it possible to protect from downloading a video from a site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790190/is-it-possible-to-protect-from-downloading-a-video-from-a-site/)

Answer (score 1):

try with .htaccess to:

- forbid directory listing
- check the urlreferrer / remote IP address

But if, depending on the way you play the file to the user, if there is a direct access to the file, it will be hard to secure.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your music file's URLs to a PHP script, check some login via session and output the music file only if the user is logged in.

You could also put a copy of a mp3, that a user is listening to with a session id in the name and remove it after the session get's invalid. This way every user has it's own URL that will not be active permanently.